# xmlstarlet: select attribute if child exists

Tags: xml, svg, xpath, xmlstarlet

I've got an svg that contains the following (trimmed down):

```
<svg
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape">
   <g
     inkscape:label="base"
     inkscape:groupmode="layer"
     id="layer1"
     transform="translate(0,-600)">
    <image
       sodipodi:absref="/Untitled.png"
       xlink:href="/Untitled.png"
       width="800"
       height="500"
       preserveAspectRatio="none"
       id="image5168"
       x="3.67"
       y="596" />
  </g>
  <g
     inkscape:groupmode="layer"
     id="layer30"
     inkscape:label="triangle">
    <path
       style="fill:none;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1"
       d="M 273,340 290,127 563,307 Z"
       id="path5174"
       inkscape:connector-curvature="0" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

[Complete XML](http://pastebin.com/uz7bnAUn)

When I query with:

`xmlstarlet sel -t -v "//_:svg/_:g/@inkscape:label" drawing.svg`

I get:

```
base
triangle
```

I've been digging through the conditionals, but I can't find a way to select `g`'s `inkscape:label` only if it contains a `path` node [or otherwise, if it doesn't contain an `image` node].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get only `g` that has child `path`, you can simply add `path` in a predicate for `g` :

```
//_:svg/_:g[_:path]/@inkscape:label
```